# multiple StreamingContext in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

When two process started i got an error like

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one StreamingContext may be started in this JVM. Currently running StreamingContext was started atorg.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start()

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Rather obviously: don't start two `StreamingContext`s at once. Look in your code for where you do so (the stack trace you didn't post should help). Use [`StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$) instead if you aren't sure if a `StreamingContext` is already started.